# Detect Mobile number change on iphone Device

Tags: ios, iphone, client-server, client-side, server-side

i Know that the client side cannot detect that the sim card has been changed on iphone devices but i'm wondering if there is a certain way to detect this change from the server side

any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by server side?

Comment: @Retro i mean not from the client side ( design interface ).. from the server database

Comment: You can get it if you have at server side using services, but i am not sure how you can have this info at your server side

Comment: @Retro what services?

Comment: Buddy please update question proper information, Your title is good but description/explanation of question is not clear

Comment: In simple word its not possible!